# Reference a directory outside of folder

Tags: python, file, directory

How do I reference a file outside of the file's folder?
I have tried src, but that does not work.

```py
f = open('src/data/beemovie.txt','r')
txt = f.readlines()
print(txt)
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide a structure of your files? Where is the script located?

Comment: Can you provide the absolute path for both the script and the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your project structure is like below:

```
src
└── data
    ├── beemovie.txt
    └── nested
        └── script.py
```

In order to enable `src/data/nested/script.py` to read parent directory files, you should use `..` to change current working directory to parent directory.

```py
with open('../beemovie.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```